# Is there a `pathos`-specific way to determine the number of CPU cores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathos

I want to determine the number of physical CPU cores to size the number of `nodes` for a  `ProcessPool` accordingly.

```
from pathos.pools import ProcessPool
process_pool = ProcessPool(nodes=?)
```

I know that `psutil` provides this number as described below.

```
import psutil
process_pool = ProcessPool(nodes=psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
```

However, is there a canonical `pathos`-specific way of adjusting the `node` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage in `pathos` is very similar to `psutil`

```
>>> import pathos as pa             
>>> pa.helpers.cpu_count()
8
```